# Bootstrap 5- link is disabled when using accordion class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a table row that expands a hidden table row when clicked using the accordion classes. The clickable row also has a  tag within the . In Bootstrap 4 that link was clickable. In bootstrap 5 clicking the link triggers the accordion instead of following the link.  Here is a snippet:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-djO3wMl9GeaC/u6K+ic4Uj/LKhRUSlUFcsruzS7v5ms=" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-fh8VA992XMpeCZiRuU4xii75UIG6KvHrbUF8yIS/2/4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <table class="table table-striped border shadow">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseRow">
          <td>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Test Link</a>
          </td>
          <td>Another Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="collapseRow" class="collapse accordion">
          <td>
            Collapsed Content
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've tried changing the z-index, but that didn't work. Any ideas how to make the  tag clickable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Having a separate action or icon it will improve also the user experience, I think this is the reason of the Bootstrap default behaviour.

**Check the DEMO below:**

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-djO3wMl9GeaC/u6K+ic4Uj/LKhRUSlUFcsruzS7v5ms=" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-fh8VA992XMpeCZiRuU4xii75UIG6KvHrbUF8yIS/2/4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <table class="table table-striped border shadow">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="w-50">Col 1</th>
            <th class="w-50">Col 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a class="px-2 rotate-90" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseRow"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" style="width: 16px;"></a>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Test Link</a>
          </td>
          <td>Another Column</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="collapseRow" class="collapse accordion">
          <td>
            Collapsed Content
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```